# Delete data points from a vector

Tags: matlab

I am supposed to delete some points from a plane following a rule, or, I could say, under a constraint, defined by a generic inequality. How can I do that, or maybe Matlab offers a function for that?

Comment: are you talking about on a plot, in a vector, or in a matrix?

Comment: I think more information is needed. How is your point data (i.e. coordinates) defined? What is the rule/inequality you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know what you are after but if you're just trying to delete data from a vector (or matrix) based on some condition, you can do the following

```
a = [ 1 3 6 4 22 41];  
delIndex = find( rem(a,2) ~= 0 ); 
a(delIndex)=[]


a =

     6     4    22
```

or the logic could be in a function (anonymous or otherwise)

```
somefunc = @(v) (v == cumsum(v));

a = [ 1 3 6 4 22 41]; 

a(somefunc(a)) = []

a =

     3     6     4    22    41
```

Comment: Hello. It's a good handle, but I don't know if it can work for constraints more complicated than a odd&even judgement. Looking forward to your further instructions and thanks very much for your attention.

Comment: Maybe I haven't made it clear enough. Say, how should I do if I need to delete some certain entries in a vector?